# Energy of hydrogen atom - Schrodinger equation

Tags: energy, wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

The wavefunction of the electron in the hydrogen atom is $ k* exp(-r/a)$ (k is the normalization constant), but it does not take n into account, whereas the solution of Schrödinger's equation ($H(wavefunction)=E*wavefunction$) says the energy of it is $E=E(0)/n^2$, but the variable in the wavefunction is $r$, and $n$ isn't there. If I apply the Hamiltonian operator on the wavefunction, no $n$ will appear, I don't understand!

Comment: The wavefunction you gave is for the _ground state_ of the hydrogen atom (n=1). Incidentally, "I need an answer as fast as possible" is usually not how you get fast answers around here.... that's just how people who volunteer their expertise work.

Comment: here is a list of other sites that might answer  a student question http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh/7470#7470

Comment: I was simply very anxious when when I wrote the post, and worried about this point of the course I hadn't understood. Everyone is not a machine who writes perfect posts that could be published in scientifical reviews, Thank you for your answer, although it is shorter than your blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation k*exp(-r/a) is the wavefunction(n=1,I=0,m=0), so n=1 = ground state. So while n does not appear explicitly in the equation, it’s really there and it’s equal to 1 in this case. The equation should really be written H x wavefunction(n) = En x wavefunction(n), En = E(0)/n^2.